# Milky way rotation data

Tags: astronomy, resource-recommendations, milky-way, galaxy-rotation-curve

Can anyone tell me where I can download sample rotation curve data for the Milky Way in csv format?

Comment: Where have you tried looking so far?

Comment: Yoshiaki Sofue has a couple papers with rotation curve data embedded in the PDF; it'd be trivial to copy it & turn it into CSV.